# Mapping data to an offset of a byte buffer allocated for an entire file versus reading the data from the file itself

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory, file-io

In a nutshell, I'm just reading [BSP files](http://www.mralligator.com/q3/) from binary and rendering them.

Initially I was doing this through reading each segment individually within the file, and dynamically allocating memory for each "lump" as it's said in the file. I realized that this was inefficient, so I decided to just allocate a single buffer, write the entire file into it, and then map data pointers (i.e., buffers of various C structs) to it specifically.

I wound up discovering an odd inconsistency while comparing the results from using one method versus the other for a particular segment of the file - notably, the [visdata](http://www.mralligator.com/q3/#Visdata) portion (the inconsistency is spotted in the actual `bitsets` member of the visdata).

And what is that inconsistency, exactly? Well...

[image]

As far as I can see, this only lies within the first five bytes. Everything after that is consistent as it should be.

Here's the layout of the segment:

```
struct bspVisdata_t
{
    int     numVectors;
    int     sizeVector;

    byte*   bitsets; //<-- data being compared
};
```

Where `bitsets` is an arbitrary sized buffer determined by the preceding integers (`numVector * sizeVector`).

(note that `byte` is just a typedef to an `unsigned char`)

---

**And here's the two different approaches I'm comparing the results with**

```
// These two lines are shown just for completeness
visdata = ( bspVisdata_t* )( mapBuffer + header.directories[ BSP_LUMP_VISDATA ].offset );
numVisdataVecs = header.directories[ BSP_LUMP_VISDATA ].length;

// First approach: seek to the offset appointed in the header + the first two members of the visdata struct
fseek( file, header.directories[ BSP_LUMP_VISDATA ].offset + sizeof( int ) * 2, SEEK_SET );

// Compute size, then read the data in
int size = visdata->numVectors * visdata->sizeVector;
visdata->bitsets = new byte[ size ]();
fread( visdata->bitsets, size, 1, file );

// Second approach: just map a pointer to the memory from an offset in the buffer itself, rather than the file
byte* buffer = mapBuffer + header.directories[ BSP_LUMP_VISDATA ].offset + sizeof( int ) * 2;
```

---

**`mapBuffer` is defined as follows**

```
fseek( file, 0, SEEK_END );
size_t fsize = ftell( file );
mapBuffer = new byte[ fsize ](); // Zero-initialize memory
fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );
fread( mapBuffer, 1, fsize, file );
```

---

...**with `header` coming right after it**

`memcpy( &header, mapBuffer, sizeof( bspHeader_t ) );`

I've done a lot of double checking and made a number of different attempts to uncover why this is happening, but I don't understand. Is there anyone who can shed some light on why this might be happening? I feel like this is something I'm missing which is more fundamental and lies beyond the scope of the code itself.

I can verify that both approaches work, because the map is rendering as it should with the changes made. Ultimately, it's not a show stopper, but it would be good to know why...

Comment: Have you opened the file in text mode, by any chance?

Comment: Nah, here's the actual line: `FILE* file = fopen( filepath.c_str(), "rb" );`